# Bluetooth MIC with poor volume and quality

Tags: audio, bluetooth, windows-11, microphone

I have a Gigabyte DesignareEX 1.0 with Sound Chip (excellent quality using Realtek Drivers and cabled Headphone and MIC) and an internal WiFi/Bluetooth chipset.

I'm trying a Bluetooth device to conduct meetings and, after had bought 3 different devices (the last a JBL Tune125BT) and an USB/Bluetooth 5.0 dongle (TPLINK UB5A), I cannot understand **why the mic loads only the 16-bit 16Khz CODEC and keeps its volume too low** - even being at 100% and compensated with 30dB in the Realtek driver.

Conducting the Windows 11 MIC test (Settings - Sound - MIC), speaking in a loud voice register only 5%-11% volume and with a "robot" tone/accent sometimes.

I disabled the motherboard Wifi/BT drivers, and I get a reasonable distance and sound quality (24-bit 48Khz) for the earphone, but MIC does not alter its bad and poor quality and volume.

Do you have any tips?
I appreciate.

Comment: Bluetooth is 100% not the thing you want to use if you want to simultaneously use microphone and speakers and get high quality audio. The bandwidth limits of Bluetooth mean that there are significant quality and delay problems and personally I wouldn't use a bluetooth headset for anything more than listening to music from a phone. The first tip would always be to get a proper wireless headset that does not use bluetooth.

Comment: I guess 2Mbps (BT 5.0) just for meetings is enough, and the JBL in Android works very well. The problem is something in Windows.

Comment: @Peregrino69, thank you for your complete answer, but my problem is related to the MIC's low volume and creepy sound - and these things only happen when connected to Windows (Android is 100%). I'm 30cm far from the computer and using a BT 5.0. All drivers are up to date; Windows 11 is up to date, etc. I'm frustrated.

Comment: Thank you @Peregrino69